# Whats better to redirect, screen resolution or user agent?

Tags: php, javascript, android, html

I've created a mobile web page for a site but I'm wondering what the best method for redirection is.  Do I redirect them based on the screen resolution or the user agent?

I would assume screen resolution would look something like this:

```
if (screen.width <= 1024) window.location.replace("http://www.site/mobile/")
else window.location.replace("http://www.site/");
```

Using PHP the script would look something like this:

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/android/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://www,site/mobile/');
```

Is one method preferred over the other? If so what are the advantages?

Comment: user agent is better. It's more reliable than screen size, but can be spoofed all the same.

Comment: Keep tablets in mind. They have large screens, but they are often served tiny pages only because they are android or ios devices.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect all mobile users or just Android? The better thing to use is feature detection for mobile devices, and then redirect based off that...which would be in Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: You could just add a popup saying "Would you like to see the mobile version of this page" so users don't get frustrated when they get thrown over to a completely new view.

Comment: @Ian, sorry that was my short example. I'm trying to redirect all mobile users with the exception of tablets.

Comment: @Vee Haha I wish more websites went off that. Too many times do I come across a website that I'm automatically presented the mobile version and either cannot find the link to the full site at all or is very hard

Comment: @Vee Concur, if you're not going to have an actual responsive design this is the way to go.

Comment: @Vee but not a *popup*... please, no popups! ;)

Comment: Are sites like these reliable for code generation: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: @Ian As far as I know the AOSP browser (And chrome) have a "See desktop site" option, which I am very grateful for.

Comment: Use a button so users can choose between versions, or just use one site that is suitable for both. Many "mobile" sites are more difficult to use and way less functional than the "full" site they replace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User agent.

In this day and age of retina displays and the fact that an Android device can be any screen resolution you can think of, there's increasingly less correlation between screen resolution and platform. In fact, there are many mobile devices (nexus 7, nexus 10, ipad 3+) with the same or greater screen resolution than desktop computers. Resolution is simply not descriptive enough.

User agent, on the other hand, is designed to tell you what's making the request. You'll know without a doubt that it's an Android or iOS device. Also, on Android, I believe tablets are not supposed to include the string "mobile" within their Android-y user-agent, for even better targeting. Similarly, the iPad and iPhone each have their own set of user agent strings that you can account for.

Comment: "You'll know without a doubt"? Barely...

Comment: @Ian care to add something constructive? are you saying that there are desktops with iphone/android user agents, or visa-versa? obviously i'm ignoring the fact that you can spoof your user agent and to some extent you're relying on the Android manufacturer to not screw up the user agent.

Comment: I'm all for user agent detection - I feel like if the user truly didn't want to be seen as the user agent they are using, they can suffer the consequences of the application doing certain things based off of that. My point was that you cannot know without a doubt. Spoofing is the problem, and in no way can guarantee what the page is being requested with

Answer (score 0):

You need to think why you made a mobile site. Does it add functionality (touch) or remove excess weight (3G) simplify navigation on smaller screens? If you made it for touch devices detect the availability of touch. If  you built it to allow easy access to small screens, screen resolution may be a choice (my SGS3 with 1200x720 will see the full one, and that would be ok with me). Switching by user agent without thinking too much is a bad idea (switching if "mobile" in UA is good though, but not all support it). Would you go to a small screen optimized site, if the user agent contains ios? Now you would not, but you could have done it a few years ago, before the iPads. What would you do with a touch enabled windows mini pc?  Think functionality, not device unless you want to update all your sites at every new device. There is no such thing as "mobile", there are so many devices with many different sizes and functions and new ones you can't yet imagine are coming out.

Write down the requirements of your mobile site (touch?) and what it adds to the plain site (better handling of small screen?), and test those. And let them chose.

Keep in mind that if you have an unlimted data plan or wifi and a device with a large screen you will find mobile sites that are crippled down versions of the full site simply annoying, while sites that allow touch navigation and enhanced functionality, and scale well on any screen size are a pleasure to navigate.

Anyway, may I suggest, when/if you do redirect, try to get to the same page on the other site, not the home page. So if you are in

```
index.php?language=en&page=about__us
```

try to redirect to

```
mobile?language=en&page=about__us
```

For a much better user experience. Do not assume  visitors get to your site from the home page.