# All Urls on the page Redirect to mobile if screen width is under 699

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Sorry for the re-post. The code seems to be good code from previous responses but is not working. The code below works perfect except I need to implement it only when the screen size is below 699. I understand server-side and client side issues and just want this to work on client side. Thank You much.

```
$('a').each(function(index, a) {
    var href = $(a).attr('href');
    $(a).attr('href', 'http://mysite.com/mobile.php?redirect=' + href;)
}
```

}

Comment: I hate that way of redirection, some devices have just a  small screen, but are able to handle the full homepage. Ok 699px is okay, but some pages do that with 1000px and that's really anoying. As yo don't now what future brings, it's possible better to handle the redirect by user agents.

Comment: What is your suggestion? PHP?

Comment: What about a Reponsive Web Design using CSS Media Queries? ;-)

Comment: I tried css media queries and this is not working. I don't know why? Must be something with other mods that are interfering.

Comment: It depends how your site is structured. But yes if you write in php you can do it easy e.g. like here: http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/detect-mobile-browseruser-agent-with-php-ipad-iphone-blackberry-and-others/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
if ( $(window).width() < 699 ) {
    // your href replacement
}
```

Comment: No not like this, I am a newbie. Do I need the onload function?

Comment: If your code is located in the `<head>`, yes. Then you need `$(document).ready(function() { ... } `

Comment: It is located in the Body. I will give it a try.

Comment: I don't get it. Nothing seems to work. The code above works perfect until I add the screen size code. Unless my cache is not clearing on my phone.

Comment: it's not the best practice to load the whole page or DOM and then redirect and load it again. Evaluating headers and then decide which page to show is the common way to do this. using User Agent is the better way, consider also this arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691234/whats-better-to-redirect-screen-resolution-or-user-agent

Comment: I forgot to mention. All I am trying to do is redirect my links on the page and all querystrings need to be intact with mysite.com/mobile.php?querystring instead of mysite.com/index.php?querystring

Answer (score 0):

look into matchMedia

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia

make sure to check if the method exists before calling it otherwise it'll give errors in ~~IE 8 and below ~~ (correction: IE 9 and below)